# How to recursively define $w^i$ for $i≥0$

Tags: recursion, combinatorics-on-words

Given a string $w$, we denote with $w^i$ the string obtained by concatenating $i$ times $w$.

How can I recursively define $w^i$ for $i≥0$?

First of all, what does "concatenate" mean in this context?

Comment: I'm going to nitpick.  You should say "$w^i$ donates the string obtained by concatonating $w$ for the number $i$ times".  "$i$ times $w$" is not clear.  ... but as you weren't entirely sure what the statement meant,  I can't really expect you to recite a non-understood definition by rote.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate just means write one after the other, so if you have two strings $a$ and $b$ the concatenation is $ab$.  In your problem $w^i$ is a string of $i\ w's$, so for $i=4$ you have $w^4=wwww$

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation of the words $u$ and $v$ is the word $uv$, e.g. if we have the alphabet $\Sigma = \{ a, b, c, d \}$ and the two words $u, v \in \Sigma^*$ (the set of all finite length words over $\Sigma$) with $u = abc$ and $v = dab$ then
$$
u \cdot v = abc \cdot dab = abcdab
$$
where $\cdot$ is the concatenation operator. 
If the context allows it, one does not write it, not unlike the multiplication operator.

Your recursive definition is something like
\begin{align}
w^0 &= \epsilon \\
w^{k+1} &= w^k \cdot w = w^k \, w
\end{align}
where $\epsilon$ is the empty word, which is the word consisting of no symbols, having length $0$. It has the property
$$
w\epsilon = \epsilon w = w \quad (w \in \Sigma^*)
$$

See [Formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) to get an introduction.

Comment: Why did you use $k$ and not $i$ in the recursive definition?

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive definition be something like $n-1$ instead of $n+1$?

Comment: The name does not really matter, you can use $i$ if you prefer it.

Comment: It is convenient here. $w^0$ we use the given first case $w^0 = \epsilon$. $w^1 = w^{0+1} = w^0 w = \epsilon w = w$, using the second base case at the second equal sign and then the property of the empty word as neutral element of concatenation. $w^2 = w^{1+1} = w \cdot w = ww$, $w^3 = w^{2+1} = ww \cdot w = www$ and so on.